# Is there a way to pass a parameter into a NATURAL subroutine?

Tags: mainframe, adabas-natural

I am new to the [NATURAL programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATURAL). I am trying to find a way that I can pass one parameter to a subroutine just like in C++ or Java. Right now I have to move everything to another variable and call the method. Thus is cumbersome and is a lot more code to write.

**Question: Can a Natural Program Sub-Routine have a parameter list like in C++ or Java?**

```
   D = passVariable1
   PERFORM FLIP-DATE
      A = D 
   END-SUBROUTINE
   newVariable = A
```

Code:

```
 DEFINE SUBROUTINE FLIP-DATE          
    #A    = #D                    
    #B    = #E                     
    #C    = #F                  
    RESET   #NMM #NDD #NCCYY                                                
 END-SUBROUTINE
```

What I would like to do.

Code:

```
   DEFINE SUBROUTINE FLIP-DATE(A,B,C,D,E,F) <-- is this possible somehow?          
     #A    = #D                    
     #B    = #E                     
     #C    = #F                  
     RESET   #NMM #NDD #NCCYY                                                
   END-SUBROUTINE
```

Comment: I answered your question below, however I do have a question. What data type is passVariable1? Is it NATURAL D (date) or T (time) format, by any chance?

Comment: Alpha is the data type that is reference with passVariable1

Comment: Ah. Date/time formatted variables have some nice features where you can play games like this. You might also want to look at the MOVE SUBSTRING statement. Disclaimer: I'm ex-SAG R&D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter data area (PDA) is a special verision of the local data area (LDA), that is used in function, external subroutine, or helproutine objects. You can either define parameters inline like

```
DEFINE DATA
PARAMETER
1 #A(N2)
1 #B(N2)
1 #C(N2)
1 #D(N2)
1 #E(N2)
1 #F(N2)
LOCAL
your local variables
END-DEFINE
…
```

Alternatively you can also create a separate source object, similar to an external LDA.

```
DEFINE DATA
PARAMETER USING pda
LOCAL
your local variables
END-DEFINE
…
```

Note that you cannot use parameters with an internal subroutine.

I suggest you start reading the [Natural documentation](http://documentation.softwareag.com/natural/a_natural_mf/natural_mf_vers.htm) on Software AG's web site, especially the "First Steps" manual, if you've never worked with this powerful language before.

Answer (score 1):

parameter-data-area can be used to pass the data to sub programs and routines.